# The document cannot be deleted since it is referenced by "X"

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-synapse

I am trying to modify Azure Synapse configurations via Terraform.

When I launch my CD pipeline in Azure DevOps I have an error with Terraform :

```
Error: waiting for the deletion of Spark Pool: (Big Data Pool Name "X" / Workspace Name "syn-X" Future#WaitForCompletion: the number of retries has been exceeded: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="DeleteSparkComputeAdfError" Message="The document cannot be deleted since it is referenced by X."
```

All my notebooks in Synapse are attached to the same cluster and I can't do otherwise. Manually if I remove Synapse workspace problem disappear. But I want to do it automatically with CD in Azure DevOps.

In Azure DevOps CD is there an alternative to:
Delete firstly Azure Synapse before Synapse spark pool ?
Or
Remove notebooks in synapse to remove references ?

**Even when I delete the notebooks, error remains the same.**

Comment: Your error message indicates that the deletion of the Spark Pool in Azure Synapse is failing because it is being referenced by existing notebooks or other resources within the Synapse workspace. This means that directly deleting the Spark Pool without first removing or reconfiguring these dependencies violates referential integrity constraints within Azure Synapse Analytics @LJRB

Comment: Hello @VinayB, how to remove or reconfiguring ? I don't find any solution

Comment: And I don't understand why I have the problem now and for month never saw this error

Answer (score 0):

> Resolving Terraform Deletion Errors in Azure Synapse Analytics via Azure DevOps CD Pipelines

With limited info obtained from the query I tries to figure out the Issue is that Terraform tries to delete a Spark Pool in Azure Synapse Analytics, but other resources still depend on it. That's why you get an error message saying that the Spark Pool cannot be deleted because of existing references. This is a typical scenario in infrastructure as code (IaC) configurations, where you need to handle the dependencies between resources well to make sure they are created and destroyed in the right order.

To fix this problem in Azure DevOps Continuous Deployment (CD) pipelines, you can try some approaches that either change the sequence of resource destruction or delete references before deleting the resources.
Here are some approaches:

- #### Remove and Re-configure

To remove or reconfigure dependencies on a Spark Pool, you would need to ensure that no active notebooks or other resources are configured to use the pool before attempting its deletion. This might involve updating your notebooks or other Synapse resources to detach from the Spark Pool or to point to a different Spark Pool if necessary.

- #### Terraform Targeted Destroy

You can perform a targeted `terraform destroy` operation that specifically targets the resources you want to remove, in the order you want to remove them. This approach requires you to manually specify the order, starting with the most dependent resources (like notebooks) before moving on to the Spark Pools and finally the Synapse workspace.

```
terraform destroy -target=azure_synapse_notebook.example -target=azure_synapse_spark_pool.example -auto-approve
terraform destroy -auto-approve
```

This command sequence first destroys the notebooks and Spark Pools explicitly before executing a general destroy, which might help with dependencies. Adjust the resource names according to your Terraform configuration.

- #### Use Terraform Dependencies Explicitly

To avoid errors when using Terraform with your Synapse workspace, Spark Pools, and other resources such as notebooks, you need to specify the dependencies between them. You can use the `depends_on` attribute in your Terraform configurations to declare that one resource depends on another, but this is usually more useful for creating resources than deleting them. You should also review and modify your Terraform configurations to handle the dependencies properly. For example, you may want to make sure that notebooks are not treated as dependent on the Spark Pool if they can be removed before it.

**Conclusion:**

If the error persists even after deleting the notebooks, it's crucial to ensure that there are no hidden dependencies or locks preventing the deletion. Adjusting your pipeline to handle dependencies more gracefully.

**Reference:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-pool-configurations

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-development-using-notebooks

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/overview